# Rails rabl set calculated field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rabl

I need to render some json data. I use rabl for this purposes....

I have such code in index.rabl:

```
collection @banks, :root => "bank", :object_root => false
attributes :id, :central_office_address, :location_id, :name, :year_of_foundation
```

it's generates me json....
But now i need to put there also some calculated field for each entry of object.

For example new field (is not in model): :exch_count and do for it something like(pseudo): :exch_count @banks[i].exchangers.count * 3

But how can i do this in ruby on rails + rabls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a block to `node` that uses the bank as a parameter:

```
node(:exch_count) {|bank| bank.exchangers.count * 3 }
```